# SQL Server : constant and variable in certificate creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I somehow can't figure out the syntax for creating my certificate. I precisely fail at naming it with a constant and a variable.

By now it looks a little like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM sys.certificates 
               WHERE name = 'Cert_' + @GroupName)
    CREATE CERTIFICATE 'Cert_' + @GroupName
    WITH SUBJECT = 'I hate pinchers'
```

Just can't get the syntax to work while keeping the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @GroupName varchar(20)
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
            FROM sys.certificates 
            WHERE name = Cert_' + @GroupName +')
   CREATE CERTIFICATE Cert_' + @GroupName +
   'WITH SUBJECT = ''I hate pinchers'''
EXEC(@query)
```